# Traffic Control user permission

Tags: linux, permissions, tc

My users need to [emulate](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem#Delaying_only_some_traffic) packet loss on RTP video streams to achieve visual effects. We are in a artistic environment and don't worry about security.

The application works only as super user. I inserted a NOPASSWD entry for my user on sudoers file but it always says:

```
% tc qdisc del dev eth0 root
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
```

I also traced `open` system calls to detect which files `tc` need write permission but I failed to find something usefull.

Comment: If you added an entry to `/etc/sudoers`, you need to use `sudo` to invoke your command.

Comment: That error can also mean that the specified network interface doesn't exist.